# Array de bytes mediante socket. No siempre recibo todos los bytes

Tags: java, array, socket

Tengo un problema a la hora de mandar una imágen como array de bytes mediante un socket en java. Consigo enviar la imágen pero aproximadamente un 50% de las veces, la imágen contiene errores. Como si se hubiesen perdido bytes. No obstante, el tamaño de la imágen es siempre el mismo.

Por aquí dejo el código de lado del cliente:

```
sock = new Socket("192.168.100.100", 1149);
File file = new File ("/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/logo.png");
String fileName = file.getName();
byte[] nameArray = new byte[fileName.length()+1];
byte[] fileArray = new byte[(int)file.length()];
byte[] byteArray  = new byte [nameArray.length+fileArray.length];

for(int i=0; i<fileName.length()+1; i++){
    if(i==fileName.length()){
        nameArray[i] = "|".getBytes()[0];
        break;
    }
nameArray[i] = (byte)fileName.toCharArray()[i];
}

FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
bis.read(fileArray,0,fileArray.length);
OutputStream os = sock.getOutputStream();

System.arraycopy(nameArray, 0, byteArray, 0, nameArray.length);
System.arraycopy(fileArray, 0, byteArray, nameArray.length, fileArray.length);
os.write(byteArray,0, byteArray.length);
os.flush();
sock.close();
```

Y de lado del servidor:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    if(args.length == 2){
        final int PORT = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        final String DESTINATION_PATH = args[1];

        int bufferSize = 6022386;
        int bytesRead = 0;
        int current = 0;

        try{
            // Create socket
            ServerSocket servsock = new ServerSocket(PORT);
            while (true) {
                System.out.println("Waiting...");
                Socket sock = servsock.accept();
                System.out.println("Accepted connection: " + sock);

                // Receive file
                byte[] byteArray = new byte[bufferSize];
                String[] header;

                DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(sock.getInputStream());
                bytesRead = dis.read(byteArray);
                current = bytesRead;
                ////


                header = getHeader(byteArray);
                byteArray = removeHeader(byteArray);
                System.out.println("Bytes Read: " + bytesRead);

                ///
                String destinationPath = "C:\\Users\\Juan\\Desktop\\" + header[0];
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(destinationPath);
                BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);

                do {
                    bytesRead = dis.read(byteArray, current, (byteArray.length-current));
                    if(bytesRead >= 0) current += bytesRead;
                }while(bytesRead > -1);

                bos.write(byteArray, 0 , current-header[0].length);
                bos.flush();
                bos.close();
                sock.close();
            }
        }catch(IOException e){ e.printStackTrace(); }
    }else{
        System.out.println("\tYou have to provide 2 arguments:");
        System.out.println("\t\t1. Port");
        System.out.println("\t\t2. Destination path");
    }
}

public static String[] getHeader(byte[] byteArray){
    final byte DIVISOR = 124;

    byte[] name = new byte[100];
    String[] ret = new String[10];

    for(int i=0; i<byteArray.length; i++){
        if(byteArray[i] != DIVISOR) { continue; }
        System.arraycopy(byteArray, 0, name, 0, i);
        break;
    }

    ret[0] = "";

    for(int i=0; i<name.length; i++){
        if(name[i] == 0) { break; }
        ret[0] += (char)name[i];
    }


    return ret;
}

public static byte[] removeHeader(byte[] byteArray){
    final byte DIVISOR = 124;
    byte[] ret = new byte[byteArray.length];
    int i=0;

    for(i=0; i<byteArray.length; i++){
        if(byteArray[i] == DIVISOR){break;}
    }

    i++;
    System.arraycopy(byteArray, i, ret, 0, byteArray.length-i);

    return ret;
}
```

Nota: A la hora de mostrar `bytesRead` por pantalla muestra la cantidad de bytes de la imágen si ésta se ha pasado correctamente o menos si ésta está borrosa, pero no entiendo a qué responde dicho error ya que es muy inconsistente.

Se que la parte del servidor está un poco confusa pero es que no dejo de tocar cosas y cuando consiga que se pase bien una imágen, el objetivo es pasar más de una.

Gracias de antemano :)